# File descriptor before a command

Tags: linux, file, file-descriptor, io-redirection

What does this mean? to have the file descriptor before a command line utility.

Example,

```
>&2 echo "Hey there! Something failed"
```

Afaik, it should have been at the end of a command line utility or a program.

```
echo "Hey there! Something failed" 1>&2
```

Which at least gives a fair readability to the reader that even the stdout is copied to stderr

I came across such a line of code in one of the Open source git-hub project. Not able to understand the usage

Comment: From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html): *The following redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.*

Comment: @Shawn If you add it in "answer" section, I shall Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the redirection operators doesn't matter - some people like putting them at the beginning of a command, some people like the end. The shell itself doesn't care.

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> The following redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.